# What is wrong with the click request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send a ajax post request to the page when clicked.My code

```
$(document).on('click', '#datadel', function(num) {
     $.ajax({
        url:'https://localhost/ajax/ajax_img.php?act=datadel',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'num':num},
        success: function(infa){
            $('#img-loag-scrin').html(infa);
        }
    }); 
    });
```

html code

```
<span id="datadel" class="sf_button_red" value="50">O`chirish</span>
```

then the value in the span should be sent as a post. what's wrong with the code I wrote

Comment: yes it is......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `span` tag doesn't have a `value` attribute. You can replace the `value` attribute with any `data` attribute, like

```
<span id="datadel" class="sf_button_red" data-value="50">O`chirish</span>
```

and the value can be retrieved using the code

```
$('datadel').data('value');
```

Answer (score 4):

The `span` element doesn't have a value attribute, you could prefix it with `data-` and get the value with `attr` or `data` method.

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#datadel', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost/ajax/ajax_img.php?act=datadel',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'num': $(this).data("value") },
        // data: { 'num': $(this).attr("data-value") }, // alternate method to get the data attribute.
        success: function (infa) {
            $('#img-loag-scrin').html(infa);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="datadel" class="sf_button_reddata" data-value="50">O`chirish</span>
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#datadel', function() {
    console.log($(this).data("value"));
    //Ajax request
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="datadel" class="sf_button_reddata" data-value="50">O`chirish</span>
```

Comment: Why not `'num': $(this).data("value")`?